# Center text in <td> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have constructed a table in html and would like to add some text within a  tag and center it. My code so far:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("mainScreen")[0].style.display = "flex";
document.getElementById("fixation").style.display = "block";
```

```css
html,
body,
.mainScreen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.mainScreen {
  display: flex;
}

#fixation {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainScreen" style="display:none">
  <table align="center">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="fixation" style="text-align:center;">+</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

When I run the code the text is always at the top of the page instead of in the absolute center. I am also trying to find a way to center the text regardless of computer screen size. Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Add `align-items: center;` to `.mainScreen`

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("mainScreen")[0].style.display = "flex";
document.getElementById("fixation").style.display = "block";
```

```css
html,
body,
.mainScreen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.mainScreen {
  display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

#fixation {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainScreen" style="display:none">
  <table align="center">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="fixation" style="text-align:center;">+</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could center the `<table>` as well:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("mainScreen")[0].style.display = "flex";
document.getElementById("fixation").style.display = "block";
```

```css
html,
body,
.mainScreen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.mainScreen {
  display: flex;
}

table, #fixation {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainScreen" style="display:none">
  <table align="center">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="fixation" style="text-align:center;">+</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```